# Is it possible to install lower version os in ipad?

Tags: install, ios, ipad

I am having an iPad2 with ios 6.0.1, I want to test an app which will be support for both ios 6 and ios 5.

Now, I want to install the ios 5 in the ipad.

is it possible to install the lower version than the current in an ipad?
(I am not willing to jailbreak it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to downgrade to iOS5. You will just have to "trick" iTunes into thinking you are restoring from one of you backups.

Just make sure to first make a backup of your current settings. Then it's just a matter of restoring from the "fake" backup(IPSW-file).

You can download an IPSW(backup file) from http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_downgrade_back_ios_5